# Creating ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor Using Executors

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I am extremely confused as to why the following cast does not work:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor timeoutControl = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implements the ScheduledExecutorService.  What's the point of this Executors call if I can't use it with an actual class.

Am I using it wrong (probably), could someone offer some guidance please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();` actually doesn't return a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

[Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29) in the `Executors` class:

```
public static ScheduledExecutorService newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() {
        return new DelegatedScheduledExecutorService
            (new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1));
}
```

The `Delegated...` classes (there's a `DelegatedExecutorService` too) are just passing all the calls to the underlying executor, the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` in this case. The comments in the code suggest that the whole point of these classes is to hide all the non-interface methods that the underlying executor might have.

In any case, it is better practice anyway to use the interface rather than the class version of the object you are working on (`List` and not `ArrayList`, `ScheduledExecutorService` and not `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`).

If you absolutely need functionality available in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and not in the `ScheduledExecutorService`, you could use the constructor of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to create an instance of it.

Comment: Great, I see I was going about it the wrong way, thank you!  After some thought, I see why.

Comment: So, according to the souce code: `scheduled = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)` and `scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`; are equivalent? I just want to be sure (I need the ThreadPoolExecutor because I want to call one of its methods).

Comment: @theyuv They're equivalent *except* that `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` deliberately makes casting it fail.

Comment: Why? To discourage what I'm doing (calling a method of the implementing class)?

Answer (score 4):

You should only use the returned executor as a `ScheduledExecutorService`, rather than casting it to a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, that makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: What if I want to change a setting that's only available on the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` Object (ie: `setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy`)?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify:

A class implementing an interface could have other methods and fields that the interface doesn't. In this case, the method returns the interface so you can't downcast this to the implementing class.