# ScheduledExecutorService or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm building an Android App which have to periodically do something in a Service. And I found that using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `ScheduledExecutorService` is preferable to `Timer`.

Can anyone explain the difference between `ScheduledExecutorService` and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and which one is more suitable for Android?

**Update**

I just found [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android) explain the difference between several way to implement repeating periodic tasks. In my case, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `AlarmManager` is more suitable.

Comment: Did you think about using the Handler?

Comment: [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) has various methods to schedule code for execution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*`ScheduledExecutorService`* is an interface (a contract) and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` implements that interface.

Since you cannot directly instantiate an interface, you have to use implementation through instantiating `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` directly or through means of factory method such as `java.util.concurrent.Executors` that returns an instance of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

e.g

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
 Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS); //returns a ScheduledFuture
```

Have a look at [Scheduled Executor Service Usage for Andriod](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is an implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService`

Answer (score 2):

[Creating ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor Using Executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200230/creating-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-using-executors)

you can also look this one

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html

if you want to use it periodically, you should use this method

scheduleAtFixedRate (Runnable, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit timeunit)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example hopefully it may help

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    public MyTask() {
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("File uploading is start1");

        System.out.println("file uploaded");
    }

}

public class ScheduledExecutorsTest {
    public ScheduledExecutorsTest() {
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int time = 10 ;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
        //scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 0L, 9L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(myTask, 3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```